# Get directory path of maven plugin in its own Mojo

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am creating a custom maven plugin. In one of its Mojos, I am reading a `Xpp3Dom` object from XML file using following code piece:

```
File pluginsFile = new File(
        "absolute-path-to-file/plugins.xml");
Xpp3Dom Xpp3DomObject = new Xpp3Dom("plugins");
try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(pluginsFile);
    Xpp3DomObject = Xpp3DomBuilder.build(reader);
    reader.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO throw exception
}
```

The XML file from which I am reading (`plugins.xml`) is stored in `src/main/resources` of the maven plugin itself. **My question is**, how do I point to that XML file without explicitly stating the absolute path to that file?

To be clear: I want this file to be under the directory of my maven plugin. It cannot be outside the maven plugin as it is a necessary part of the maven plugin and should not be changed by other maven projects that consume this plugin.

I have searched for a variable/method in Maven Mojo that would give me the absolute location of the maven plugin itself. If I get that, then I can just give the location as `value-of-that-variable/src/main/resources/plugins.xml`. But I am unable to find such variable. I have also tried for a way to pass properties from Maven plugin POM to one of its Mojos so that I can pass `project.build.directory`, but cannot find a way.

To be clear: I want to access a file that is under the maven plugin directory, in one of its Mojos.

Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest form to read some of the own plugin's resources files is through the `getResourceAsStream()` API, because sooner or later, your plugin will be delivered as a JAR, and then the `src` directory will dissapear and there will remain only *classpath resources*:

```
try (InputStream input=getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("plugins.xml")){
    try(Reader reader=new InputStreamReader(input));
    {
        Xpp3Dom Xpp3DomObject = Xpp3DomBuilder.build(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Anyway, in this way there is a risk that some other JAR of the classpath should contain a `plugins.xml` file by chance. To avoid (or at least reduce) this risk, you should *package* it:

```
src\
    main\
        resources\
            foo\
                bar\
                    MyMojo.java
                    plugins.xml
```

... and in this case, you must read it through `getClass().getResourceAsInputStream()`.

Comment: That worked! I had tried `getClassLoader().getResource("fileName")` and directly using that resource file in `Xpp3DomBuilder.build()` as input. But I got an error saying `absolute-path-to-plugin-jar/jarName!/fileName` does not exist. However using `getResourceAsStream` and saving it in a temporary file using `OutputStream` and using that file worked. Any idea why using it directly did not work?

Comment: And just to clarify for anyone else, `Xpp3DomBuilder.build(input)` does not work. Input needs to be a file.

Comment: Why it didn't work directly? I suppose you were trying to create a `File` using the URL returned by `getResource`, which are incompatible types. That's why I recommended you to use `getResourceAsStream`, which returns an `InputStream`, so you can avoid using the `File` API.